# Kentico form Layout - How do I have fields that are visable based on other fields not take up space on the page when not visible

Tags: forms, layout, kentico

I have a Kentico form where I have many fields that are only visible based of other fields. The issue I am having is that when I go to make the layout there does not seem to be a way to not have this hidden fields take up space on the page. So when a user is looking at the form there is a big blank space where the hidden fields are until a selection is made and if the selection is not one where these fields become visible the blank space on the form doesn't go away

[image]

Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably used *visibility: hidden;* in your css. This makes the element still take up space.
If you use *display: none;* instead the element will not take up space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a styling issue: probably your controls are wrapped with some element (e.g. div, etc.) which has fixed height. Just use chrome inspector to see the layout and its styles.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using custom layout instead of the default, so check the HTML in the layout for anything with height defined.